# Requiring help with seed oil

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Which pipe would i use to pump my seed oil into carpenter?  I have seed oil in my carpenter and I have a waterproof cobblestone pipe connecting from the squeezer to my Carpenter.

Comment: I'm assuming this is for Feed the Beast, or are you using Forestry on its own?

Comment: also which pack?

Answer (score 1):

You need a wooden waterproof pipe at the side where you draw the oil out and you need a engine connected to this pipe (I would recommend redstone engine in this case). To count as connected, the engine must face the pipe. Also the engine must be on. To transport the liquid or pump it in another machine use waterproof pipes like cobblestone, gold etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually see the seed oil in the pipes? I forget which machines auto-eject liquids, but you may need to use a wooden waterproof pipe with a redstone engine to pump the liquids out of the Squeezer.

If you can see the seed oil in the pipes, make sure the cobblestone pipe is connecting with the Carpenter; if it isn't try breaking pipe and re-adding it. It shouldn't matter which side the oil is being pumped into.